# Faience icons for battery indicator

Tags: indicator, icons

I'm using the Faience Azur icon theme, and my Battery indicator displays ugly icons when the computer is plugged in and at some other times too:

[image: Battery indicator - charged]

[image: Battery indicator - charging]

*(I'll add more problematic icons when I see them)*

I've seen several questions about linking in battery icons from other themes, but looking at the theme, I see that a great icon already exists for a plugged-in battery:

[image: Battery icons]

I also see a bunch of battery icons prefixed with `xfpm` and `gpm`.

I assume the reason the Battery Indicator doesn't show some icons correctly is because the icon for that status is incorrectly named and the indicator doesn't recognize the name.

**How do I correctly set up the Battery Indicator to use icons from the Faience theme?**

Comment: @UriHerrera Shouldn't I look in `ubuntu-mono-dark` or `ubuntu-mono-light`?

Comment: Those are gnome's, Humanity's (ubuntu-mono-X) are different. I believe they're the icons that have the suffix -symbolic

Comment: @UriHerrera What do you mean, "those are gnome's, Humanity's are different"?

Comment: @UriHerrera I just checked the gnome and Faience icon themes and the icons I'm getting are in `Faience/status/scalable`, such as `battery-caution-charging-symbolic.svg`. Should I try copying the correct icons to new icons named after the symbolic icons? And what size would I use?

Comment: Try deleting the symbolic icons, I guess it's because of the version of Gnome that you have that loads those instead of the regular icons. If not you'll have to edit the symbolic icons to make them look like you want, the size won't matter since they're SVGs.

Comment: I tried renaming the symbolic icon by adding `.OLD` to the end, and the Battery Indicator disappeared until I renamed it back to the original. I don't see why I should have to edit the symbolic icons, other themes work correctly. Is there any way to find out the names of the battery icons that are missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**

I got it working.

[image: faience battery icons]

I had to rename some icons and add some. Follow these steps:

- Download the `faience_battery_icons.tar.gz` using the link below.
- Extract the file.

```
tar xzf faience_battery_icons.tar.gz
```

- Copy all the icons inside the `faience_battery_icons` folder to the `status/22/` directory of the *Faience* icon theme directory. The icon directory can be one of the following:

  - `~/.icons/Faience/`
  - `/usr/share/icons/Faience/`
- For example, if the icon directory is `~/.icons/Faience`, then you have to paste all the icons inside the `faience_battery_icons` to `~/.icons/Faience/status/22`.

```
cp faience_battery_icons/* ~/.icons/Faience/status/22/
```

- Done!

**Download Link:** [faience_battery_icons.tar.gz](https://www.dropbox.com/s/haoawbgunm1dtxl/faience_battery_icons.tar.gz)

---

**Alternate (previous) answer:**

I was using **Faenza** icon theme and for some reason the battery icon looked like this:

[image]

However, for the **ubuntu-mono-dark** theme, the icons were fine. So I just copied the battery icons from the **ubuntu-mono-dark** theme, and the icons now are better:

[image]

The reason, I think, is that either the icons are not named properly or some icons are missing.

Comment: As I show in my question, there are great icons already, they must just be named wrong. So if possible, I'd prefer using the actual icons, not the icons from `ubuntu-mono-dark`.

Comment: will get back with the answer :)

Comment: Got it working! If you've any problems, reply back.

Comment: This looks like it will work. I've recently installed Kubuntu 13.04   as a dual-boot and it messed up my Ubuntu 12.10 system a bit, so I haven't had a chance to test this, but I'll try to test it before the bounty runs out so I can accept you answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that works for me in Raring 13.04 with gnome 3.6*

Run this command:

```
sudo cp -r /usr/share/icons/Faience-Claire/status/* /usr/share/icons/Faience/status/
```

Answer (score 0):

Just copy the icons you like and rename like the ones you dislike (after deleting them). It's easy.

Comment: But great icons already exist - the question is what are the correct names to use to have the system recognize and use them.